# Receiver (<MainViewController: 0x8e34580>) has no segue with identifier 'showCompleted' iOS 7

Tags: ios, ios7, uiviewcontroller, segue

So I am really frustrated with what is going on in my app.  I have a segue set up in interface builder that I am calling programatically.  It works just fine when I call the segue with a method within the class.  I have (in MainViewController.m)

```
-(void)presentCompletedFormsView{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showCompleted"];
}
```

This works totally fine when I call it from inside this VC's class.  But when I call this method from another viewcontroller (my menu viewController that is presented on top of this Main one), I get the error

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver (<MainViewController: 0x8e34580>) has no segue with identifier 'showCompleted''
```

This is how I am calling it from the other class:

```
-(void)presentController{
    MainViewController *vc = [[MainViewController alloc] init];
    [vc presentCompletedFormsView];
}
```

**EDIT**

I have already tried the obvious solutions:
  - Cleaning and building
  - Resetting data
  - Changing the name of the segue

to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems. Firstly, and most seriously, you can't call a segue from another controller, because MainViewController's view isn't in the window's hierarchy when you're trying to do that, which means it can't present another controller. Secondly, the instance of MainViewController that you create with alloc init is not he one you made in the storyboard that has the segue connected to it.  You need to rethink your structure to make is work. The easiest way would be to connect the segue from the MenuViewController, but that might not be the structure you want.

Comment: I just need some way to be able to modally present a viewcontroller onto my main viewController, using a button on a different viewController that is also being presented on the main view controller

Comment: @tyler53, sorry, but you can't do that, you need to present it from that different controller. Why don't you want to do that? The visual effect will be the same.